# Can you write multiple IP packets in one write to the linux tun device?

Tags: packets, tun

I have seen (by actually reading a tun device) that the tun driver on linux can return multiple IP packets in a single read. Is the reverse true - can you write multiple IP packets in a single write to the tun device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually multiple packets were returned by the driver because it had been enhanced locally. The tun driver that comes with linux only returns one packet per read. The driver also expects only one packet per write.

Comment: Where can I get this enhanced tun driver from?  (I have a bottle-neck on writing packets into tun0.  Writing multiple packets per context-switch may help.)